# What's the difference between using void func(struct myStruct s) and void func(myStruct s), if both work the same way?

Tags: c++

I always see people using it this way:

```
struct myStruct{
 ...
};

void func(struct myStruct s){
 ...
}
```

But I use it this way, omitting the "struct"

```
void func(myStruct s){
 ...
}
```

and it still works, so is there a difference?

Comment: Is it C or C++? The second is legal C++ but not C.

Comment: if it is `C` there must be `typedef struct myStruct myStruct` somewhere

Comment: Yeah I was using it in an IDE, so C++. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void func(myStruct s){
 ...
}
```

It will result in `undefined type mystruct` error in C, unless you used `typedef` to make `mystruct` a alias for datatype.
A `typedef` statement like,

```
typedef struct myStruct myStruct;
```

will make `myStruct` a alias for `struct myStruct` so both are same.
In C++ both will work.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is compatible with C, but it also does not require typing `struct` when declaring struct variable (the same is with classes).
So in C++ both

```
void func(struct myStruct s); //compatibility with C
```

and

```
void func(myStruct s); //C++ like declaration
```

are correct.